# I have a fragment that holds a chart view that gets reset on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment
{
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private static final String selectedChildTracker = "selectedChild";
    static ArrayList<String> subjects;
    static csBar cShowProgress = csBar.getInstance();
    BarChart chart;
    Button loadChart;
    BarData data;
    View card = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

            card =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,null);
            chart = (BarChart) card.findViewById(R.id.chart);
            loadChart = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.graph_loader);
            sharedpreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(selectedChildTracker, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            final String activeChild = sharedpreferences.getString("selectedChild",null);
            final String week = "4";
            final String term = "First Term";
            final String session = "2015/2016";

            loadChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Request(week,term,session,activeChild);
                }
            });

        return card;
    }
}
```

The issue i have is when the load chart button is clicked, the chart gets loaded properly, however when the orientation is changed or the user visits another page the chart data gets cleared and the fragment is reset. I've never used fragment in this way, so i'm quite confused as to how to handle the issue.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in your manifiest file under **application** tag

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

this will handle screen rotation issues